# Access fastapi.Request object without router method

Tags: fastapi, starlette

I have a FastAPI `app` and on app-startup, I create a `State` for it like this:

`app.state.player["id"] = Player()`

And now I want to access this `player` state whenever I need it. And the only way of accessing this state is through `fastapi.Request` object like this:

`request.app.state.player["id"]`

I tried this:

```
def _return_player(request: Request):
    return request.app.state.player["id"]

async def process_new_player(player: Player = Depends(_return_player)):
    await player.play()
```

but apparently `fastapi.Depends` can be used only inside router methods.

And then I wanted to do something like this:

```
async def process_new_player():
    player = request.app.state.player["id"]
    await player.play()
```

but again I was not sure how to get the value of `fastapi.Request`. And no, the `process_new_player` method is not initiated from any router at the very beginning (if that was the case I could pass the `fastapi.Request` object recursively to here).

How can I access the value of `request.app.state.player["id"]` inside `process_new_player` method?

I already know about the [starlette-context](https://starlette-context.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, but I want a solution without a 3rd party and a simpler one.

Thanks!

Comment: If this is an application wide variable that is to be used outside of a FastAPI context, what is the reason for attaching (and then subsequently attempting to use it outside of) to the FastAPI object in the first place? How are you calling `process_new_player`? (i.e. is there any reason not to call it on app startup where you attach the state variable as well?) It's a bit hard to understand what the use case is compared to "just" having a state container outside  of the FastAPI app object

Comment: I was wrong about my presumption that I can access `State` object only through  `Request` object. I just accessed `player` state by: `app.state.player["id"]`.
You don't need `Depends` or `Request` for that.

Comment: No, but this is _app_ state. Not request state. If your application is only in use by a single player, sure - that could work. But for values that are specific per request and represents the current user, use `Depends` or `Security` in your view endpoint definition